# Can I align the stem-beams in MuseScore?

Tags: musescore, beaming

I am writing drums exercises and I want to get a clear visual helping to read the timing.

Is it possible to align vertically all the beams? By default it depends on the note-pitch so it may vary.
[image: Horizontal beams on sixteenth notes, but not vertically aligned]

I know it's possible to move them manually, but did I miss any option or tool to align them all automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Select the beams and, in the element inspector, check the "custom position" box. However, this can only be done in pairs of beam sets; MuseScore does not allow more than two beam groups to be selected at one time.

**MuseScore default beaming**

[image: MuseScore default beaming example]

**Beam selected and element inspector**

[image: Beams selected and element inspector]

**Custom Position selected and Y Position set**

[image: Beam after setting Custom Y Position]

**Note 1:** Using Force Horizontal (or setting horizontal beaming in the Style properties) does not allow for vertical alignment.

**Note 2:** Vertical alignment can also be achieved by forcing all notes to be beamed, which can be done using the beam properties tool. However, this doesn't work well across bar lines. Within a measure, sixteenth note groups can be connected by an eighth note beam, but across measures, the beam has to be sixteenth notes (or whatever the prevailing note type is).